# Case insensitive regular expression in rule-based row splitter in KNIME

Tags: regex, case-insensitive, knime

How to change this String expression so the rule it will be case insensitive
`join("$yourSentenceColumn$ MATCHES \".*?\\Q", removeChars($yourTermColumn$, "\""), "\\E.*\" => TRUE")`?

Answer (score 0):

The following String Manipulator expression should do what you need:

```
join("$document$ MATCHES \"(?i).*?\\Q", removeChars($term$, "\""), "\\E.*\" => TRUE")
```

Note the `(?i)` part, it makes the regular expression case insensitive: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE

Comment: Thank you again :)